# How to send reference android:drawable to a Native Module Android in React Native

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I've a big problem with React Native and my android library for React native.

I'm developing a npm package for react native and the specific problem is that I need the next functionality:

1) On react native project the user can be add a new drawable.

2) User need send to the library the reference of the drawable like as R.drawable.my_image ( int )
Sample:

```
//this function must be called from ReactNative in the Javascript App.js file
RNImageLibrary.loadDrawable(R.drawable.my_image).
```

3) In my library I need to load this Resource.

but I don't know how do this.

Any Idea? Sorry for my english.